# How to pass secured data from one single page app to another

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on developing a single HTML page application using require.js, jquery.js.

My requirement is to launch a new URL (different app URL) from my HTML page. Also, I need to send few sensitive details (ex. password) from my HTML page to new URL.

E.g: http://myapp.com/#home  to  http://otherapp.com/#newpage

I was trying to send data by using forms. But, in my new URL (it is also single page developed using Java script), I am not seeing this data using Java script.

Please help me on finding the best way to share my sensitive data from my HTML page to new URL using POST.

I use Java script at both places to send and receive data.

Thanks
Naresh.D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use ***[localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)*** and then using XAuth you can share it. [Example](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/)
   **NOTE :-** Though passing of sensitive information using this technique might not be safe...
2. You can even do it using ***[postMessage](http://ejohn.org/blog/postmessage-api-changes/)***. This might be a bit tricky.. [Example](http://html5demos.com/postmessage2)

Some useful link's I found:
1. [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro)
2. [NCZ Online](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)
3. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Client side JavaScript, running in a webpage, cannot access the POST data from the request used to fetch that page.

If you want it to be available, then you must use a server side program to insert the data into the HTML of the page.